# Get all rows in a particular table in all databases in a particular server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have around 700 databases in my live server. All these databases have a table named `LogTbl` in them. I need to make a list of all rows in this table for all the 700 databases.

So far I've tried

```
Declare @ServerName nvarchar(500), @dbName nvarchar(500), @key int, @msg_id int, @text nvarchar(max), @source nvarchar(max), @logdate datetime 


SELECT name FROM sys.databases FOR XML AUTO

select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where TABLE_NAME = 'logtbl'
```

And then I've no idea. I need to return 1 result set with the following fields

```
Servername, database, key, msg_id, text, source, logdate
```

where  `key, msg_id, text, source, logdate` are the table columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this :

```
create table #tbl (table_name varchar(500))

exec sp_msforeachdb 'insert into #tbl select table_name from [?].information_schema.tables'

select * from #tbl
```

take care with sp_msforeachdb of the system database.
You can imagine to make inside the sp_msforeachdb an if clause where the table_name logtbl should exists.

Comment: the OP question ask to be on one result set

Comment: Just be aware that sp_MSforeachdb is not officially supported by Microsoft and so in theory could be dropped in future releases.

Comment: This is good code and I get all the tables that I need. Now I need all rows for each of this tables.